# How to visualise a calculation running in another thread in real time with vtk

Tags: c++, pthreads, vtk

I would like to visualise a running calculation in another thread with the visualisation tool kit in real time. The calculation spits out a new set of values to be visualised each iteration and the graphical thread must some how know this and load the new values.

One way to do this would be to have the main thread poll the state of the calculation. Ideally I'd not like to do any polling but if there is no other way then I will.

The best way I can think of would be to have the the calculation thread push an event onto the main thread's event queue every iteration of the calculation which is then processes by the GUI. I'm not sure how to go about doing this, or if it can be done in a thread safe manner.

I'm using vtk in gcc/C++ on linux using pthreads.

Answer (score 2):

Listen to the Modified event on the object you're interested in, in the main thread using a vtkCommand (or appropriate derived class). You can then update your renderer and associated classes when the callback occurs.

But many VTK classes aren't thread-safe. You'll need to pause updation while rendering occurs. Otherwise, it'll segfault while trying to read and write the same memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a standard way. Create separate thread for window handling (i.e. window messages processing), and sometime put data into window (i.e. update the image).

Similar procedure with MathGL looks like following (see [How I can create FLTK/GLUT/Qt window in parallel with calculation?](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/mathgl_en/mathgl_en_6.html))

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <mgl/mgl_fltk.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

mglPoint pnt;  // some global variable for changable data
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int sample(mglGraph *gr, void *)
{
  gr->Box();  gr->Line(mglPoint(),pnt,"Ar2"); // just draw a vector
  return 0;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void *mgl_fltk_tmp(void *)      {       mglFlRun();     return 0;       }
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
  mglGraphFLTK gr;
  gr.Window(argc,argv,sample,"test");  // create window
  static pthread_t tmp;
  pthread_create(&tmp, 0, mgl_fltk_tmp, 0);
  pthread_detach(tmp);    // run window handling in the separate thread
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)   // do calculation
  {
    sleep(1);             // which can be very long
    pnt = mglPoint(2*mgl_rnd()-1,2*mgl_rnd()-1);
    gr.Update();          // update window
  }
  return 0;   // finish calculations and close the window
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```